# how to get exact id values of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to sort out this problem but have yet to get results. I tried to get the exact id values of the row which I edit in order to perform an update.

I can get get my current cell value but I can't get the corresponding id values of the cell. I iterate over the table id value which in turn get's all the id values of the table.

I'm using this jquery code for iteration:

```
$('#table').ready(function() { 
     $(this).find('.filename').each( function() { 
          alert($(this).html()); 
     }) 
})
```

Then I tried this simple JavaScript:

```
var fid= document.getElementById("filename").textContent;
```

It gets only the first id value of the table.
For example, if I edit the first row the id value is 53.
If I edit the second row the id value should be 52 but it gets only 53.

See [**this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121108/passing-cell-value-inorder-to-update-table-using-ajax-post), I have posted this question previously.

Comment: Can you include the relevant html?

Comment: Include some live code or an example...

Comment: On a side-note: If you are already using jQuery you should stick with it when using selectors. `$("#filename").text()/.val()/.html()` rather than `document.getElementById("filename").textContent` Using 2 different types of syntax for selectors is just more confusing than beneficial.

Comment: did u guys chk that link in my question it has got wht u want i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi thanks for ur response ,i tried a different script and it was working as i thought
here is the code

```
function doubleclick(table,id1)
        {

            table.innerHTML="<input type=text name=tab onBlur=\"javascript:submitNewName(this,'"+id1+ "');\" value=\""+table.innerHTML+"\">";
            table.firstChild.focus();
           // alert(id1);
        }
        function submitNewName(text,id2)
        {
            text.parentNode.innerHTML=text.value;
            $.ajax({
        url: 'update',
         data:{text1:text.value,fileid1:id2},
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        error:function(data){
           //alert('error')
        },
        success: function(data) {
            //alert('updated!')
        }
    });

        }
```

html:
//when double clicked it will pass both ${item.filedesc},${item.id}

```
<td ondblclick="javascript:doubleclick(this,${item.id});" >${item.filedesc}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementById` gets the element and not the id. The id is what you are providing as parameter.

You could simply do:

```
$('#table').ready(function() { 
     $(this).find('.filename').each( function() { 
          alert(this.id); 
     }) ;
});
```

Instead of cluttering the DOM with id's (which should always be unique) you could always use the data-attributes of elements:

```
<tr data-identifier="53"><td></td></tr>
```

```
$('#table').ready(function() { 
     $(this).find('.filename').each( function() { 
          // if this is the row
          alert($(this).data('identifier')); 
     }) ;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure that i understand your question but this will give you ids of all cells within a table:

```
  $("#table > td").each(function(){
      alert($(this).attr("id"));
  });
```