# Pass parent form and modal window data to server with AJAX

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a dynamic form page with multiple table rows where the user updates the status by selecting the checkbox for the rows to update.  When the update button is clicked, I open a jquery modal window for the user to select a status from a dropdown list and enter comments.  I am able to pass the modal window data to my servlet through AJAX but I don't know how to get the checkbox values.

How can I pass the checkbox values from the parent form and the additional data from the modal window to my Java servlet so I can update the appropriate database records?  I would like to use AJAX so the parent form doesn't reload for the user.

Thanks in advance!

**Modal window and AJAX update:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Update Status": function() {
                dataString = $("#statusForm").serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'updateStatus',
                    data: dataString,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {alert(data);}
                });
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
        },
        close: function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
    });
    $("#update-status")
            .button()
            .click(function() {
        $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

As you can see there are 4 items checked in the background with the modal window on top asking for additional information.The items selected need to updated with the information from the modal windows.  Each checkbox has it's own unique value corresponding to it's record id in the database table.

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

Parent form - HTML Code snippet:

```
<form name="OptionList">
<table id="statusTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Option</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Timestamp</th>
            <th>Entry Type</th>
            <th>User Profile</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="19"></td>
        <td>DO</td>
        <td>5/14/13 4:31 PM</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>user profile</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="61" ></td>
        <td>DO</td>
        <td>5/14/13 4:50 PM</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>user profile</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="37"></td>
        <td>DO</td>
        <td>5/14/13 5:03 PM</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>user profile</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="157"></td>
        <td>DO</td>
        <td>5/14/13 5:04 PM</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>user profile</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This still isn't working for me. How can I get the checkbox values from my form "OptionList" (background of image above) and pass them to my servlet controller when my modal window "Update Status" (modal window overlay in image above) button is clicked? My modal window form is called "StatusForm".

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing at present is seralizing the entire form and passing it to your modal :

`dataString = $("#statusForm").serialize();`

Instead, what you need to do is simply pass the data for the row that you are interested in. For this to work you could assign numeric ids to each row and parse the data for the checkbox having that parent id.

See this solution: [passing cell value inorder to update table using ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121108/passing-cell-value-inorder-to-update-table-using-ajax-post?rq=1)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't entirely clear with my example. The serialization part is working correctly because it's for the data in my modal window. What I'm missing is a way to capture/pass the checkbox values from the parent form.